# How to solve this Android request keyword error?

Tags: android, xml, onactivityresult

MainActivity.java :

```
package com.example.dell.capcrop;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;



public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    final int CAMERA_CAPTURE=1;
    private  Uri picUri;
    final int PIC_CROP=2;
    Bundle bundle;
    Bitmap bitmap;
    ImageView img;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button captureBtn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.capture_btn);
        captureBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v){
        if (v.getId()==R.id.capture_btn){
            try {
                Intent captureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                startActivityForResult(captureIntent,CAMERA_CAPTURE);
            }

            catch (ActivityNotFoundException anfe){
                String errorMessage ="Whoops - your device doesn't support capturing image";
                Toast toast=Toast.makeText(this,errorMessage,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.show();
            }
        }
    }



    private void performCrop() {
        try{
            Intent cropIntent=new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
            cropIntent.setDataAndType(picUri,"image/*");
            cropIntent.putExtra("crop","true");
            cropIntent.putExtra("aspectX",1);
            cropIntent.putExtra("aspectY",1);
            cropIntent.putExtra("outputX",256);
            cropIntent.putExtra("outputY",256);
            cropIntent.putExtra("return_data",true);
            startActivityForResult(cropIntent,PIC_CROP);
        }
        catch (ActivityNotFoundException anfe)
        {
            String errorMessage="Whoops - your device doesn't support capturing image";
            Toast toast=Toast.makeText(this,errorMessage,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(requestCode==request&&resultCode==RESULT_OK)
        {
            bundle=data.getExtras();
            bitmap=(Bitmap)bundle.get("data");
            img.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            Thread thread=new Thread()
            {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        sleep(2000);
                        Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),result.class);
                        bundle.putParcelable("bmp",bitmap);
                        intent.putExtras(bundle);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        finish();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            };
            thread.start();
        }

        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == CAMERA_CAPTURE) {
                picUri = data.getData();
                performCrop();

            } else if (requestCode == PIC_CROP) {
                Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
                Bitmap thePic = extras.getParcelable("data");
                ImageView picView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.picture);
                picView.setImageBitmap(thePic);
            }

        }
    }
    }
```

My app is basically a sign language interpreter and I need to remove an error. Here is the code in which there is multiple `onactivityresult()` definition which is causing error. I do some changes but all in vain. In this code the mobile camera capture image and show a frame in which the user crop the required part of image and show in the next activity.

Comment: What does that Thread do in onActivityResult?

Comment: In first the image go to the second activity image as bitmap and in second crop image show in next activity

Comment: if(requestCode==request&&resultCode==RESULT_OK) , what is "request" there??

Comment: Use as a parameter...